# How do you prove ∃x[Fx → (Gx → Hx)], ∀xFx ∧ ∃xGx ∴ ∃x¬(Gx ∧ ¬Hx) in FOL?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Given:**

```
∃x[Fx → (Gx → Hx)]

∀xFx ∧ ∃xGx
```

**Prove:**

```
∃x¬(Gx ∧ ¬Hx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting off:

```
∃x[Fx → (Gx → Hx)]
∀xFx ∧ ∃xGx
```

We know that F is true for all x (because `∀xFx`), so we can replace Fx with true in the first statement.

`∃x[true → (Gx → Hx)]`

We know that A → B is short for ¬A V B, so we can do that here:

```
∃x[¬(true) V (Gx → Hx)]
∃x[false V (Gx → Hx)]
```

We know that `false or X` is equal to X:

```
∃x[false V (Gx → Hx)]
∃x[(Gx → Hx)]
```

And we can apply the definition of implies (→) again:

```
∃x[(Gx → Hx)]
∃x[¬Gx V Hx]
```

And finally we can use De Morgan's law (`(A V B) <=> ¬(¬A ∧ ¬B)`) to invert the contents of the brackets, and simplify not-nots:

```
∃x[¬Gx V Hx]
∃x[¬(¬(¬Gx) ∧ ¬(Hx))]
∃x[¬(¬¬Gx ∧ ¬Hx)]
∃x[¬(Gx ∧ ¬Hx)]
∃x¬[Gx ∧ ¬Hx]
```

Which is what you wanted to prove.